# vba When inserting file, margins in new section disappearing

Tags: vba, ms-word, insert, document

I want to insert DocB' into DocA using the VBA code:
Selection.InsertFile DocB.

DocA is a normal document in every regard.

DocB has 2 sections.  The first is 'normal' stuff. The second section (properly marked with a Section Break/Next Page) has a new set of left and right margins.

When DocB is inserted into DocA with the above VBA command, all formatting (fonts, spacing, etc.) EXCEPT that the margins in the second section of DocB don't carry into DocA. (The Section Break/New Page marker is still present and visible in the 'assembled' document.)

Why are my margins being erased/ignored with a Selection.InsertFile command?

(I can manually copy and paste the content of DocB into DocA without issue.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Be sure to check out the [tour], as well as [ask].  What have you tried so far to solve this problem?  Please share your code as well as screenshots to better illustrate what `'normal' stuff`, ` 'assembled' etc mean: what you're starting with, what you're getting, and what you want to get.  (You can always [edit] your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word stores margin settings, headers, footers and similar layout information in the section breaks. For the last section of a document (or the only section if there are no section breaks) this information is stored "in" the last paragraph mark.

When you copy/paste a document, that last paragraph mark with the section formatting is included.

When you use VBA to insert a file, that last paragraph mark is cut off. That's why you're losing the margins. In order to retain that information, before you insert the file you need to add a section break (probably continuous) to the end of the document. This is basically what the Master-/Subdocument functionality does, by the way.

Comment: Okay. The 'tip' on using Comment in StackOverflow say don't use it for 'Thanks'. But I don't see a place for saying 'That worked. Thanks.' I hope I am not violating the rules, but 'That worked. Thanks, Cindy.'