# Maintain formatting when merging word documents in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I've searched and have been unable to find the right solution. I have multiple word documents I wish to merge. When I go to merge I lose the page formatting (single line spacing and 0pt for space before and space after) When I merge, these settings revert back to multi line and 8pt for space after. So, I created a blank page template, but after merge it still won't maintain formatting.

```
    class Word_Merge
    {
public static void Merge(string[] filesToMerge, string outputFilename, bool insertPageBreaks)
{
    Word._Application wordApplication = new Word.Application();
    object pageBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage;
    object outputFile = outputFilename;
    object fileName = @"S:\template.docx";
    object end = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;

    try
    {
        wordApplication.Visible = false;
        Word.Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(ref 
        fileName);                
        Word.Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;
        wordDocument.PageSetup.TopMargin = (float)50;
        wordDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin = (float)50;
        wordDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin = (float)50;
        wordDocument.PageSetup.BottomMargin = (float)50;
        selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = 
        Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle;
        selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0.0F;
        selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0.0F;

        foreach (string file in filesToMerge)
        {
            if (file.Contains("Scores.docx"))
            {
                selection.PageSetup.PaperSize = 
                Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaper11x17;
                selection.Collapse(ref end);
            }
            selection.InsertFile(file);

            if (!file.Contains("Scores.docx") && insertPageBreaks)
            {
                selection.InsertBreak(pageBreak);
            }
        }

        wordDocument.SaveAs(ref outputFile);
        wordDocument = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        wordApplication.Quit();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you try this: [Serialize your content as a JSON string and format it.](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/mar/31/prettifying-a-json-string-in-net)

Comment: save your `wordDocument` as a JSON string by serializing it. Then pretty format it again as mentioned in that article.

Comment: See my Answer in this thread. Even though it's about VBA the same principle applies: you need a section break at the end of the documents you're inserting in order to retain things like margins, headers, footers, newspaper columns and similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vba When inserting file, margins in new section disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962749/vba-when-inserting-file-margins-in-new-section-disappearing)

Comment: For a VBA solution, see: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?51797-Macro-to-merge-mulitple-word-doc-into-one-word-doc&p=354835&viewfull=1#post354835. I'll leave you to do any C# conversions.

Comment: If you want to share your own knowledge, **post the answer as an answer and do not edit your original question**.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this out on my own, here is the code that has worked for me.

```
    class Word_Merge
{
    public static void Merge(string[] filesToMerge, string outputFilename, bool insertPageBreaks)
    {
        Word._Application wordApplication = new Word.Application();
        object pageBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakContinuous;
        object outputFile = outputFilename;
        object fileName = @"S:\ODS\Insight 2 Oncology\Quality Division Project\Visual Review Scores\Scoring Template\MergeTemplate.docx";
        object end = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;

        try
        {
            wordApplication.Visible = false;
            Word.Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(ref fileName);                
            Word.Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;


            foreach (string file in filesToMerge)
            {
                if (file.Contains("Scores.docx"))
                {
                    selection.PageSetup.PaperSize = Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaper11x17;
                    selection.PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;                      
                    selection.InsertFile(file);
                    selection.Collapse(ref end);
                }                    

                if (!file.Contains("Scores.docx") && insertPageBreaks)
                {                        
                    selection.InsertFile(file);
                    selection.InsertBreak(pageBreak);
                }
            }

            wordApplication.Selection.Document.Content.Select();
            wordDocument.PageSetup.TopMargin = (float)50;
            wordDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin = (float)50;
            wordDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin = (float)50;
            wordDocument.PageSetup.BottomMargin = (float)50;
            selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle;
            selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0.0F;
            selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0.0F;

            wordDocument.SaveAs(outputFile + ".docx");
            wordDocument.Close();
            wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(outputFile + ".docx");
            wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(outputFile + ".pdf", Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
            wordDocument = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            wordApplication.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```